# How can I cluster/group the output of a supervised classifier?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis

This is a model of my problem:

I start with a list of datapoints

```
X = ['Apple','Peach','Orange','Dog','Elephant','Fox','Cat','Mango']
```

Then I have the output of a supervised classifier which leads me to classes such as:

```
Y = clf.predict(X) # 'FRUIT','FRUIT','FRUIT','ANIMAL','0','ANIMAL','ANIMAL','FRUIT'
```

Even in a perfect world where my classifier has no FN I'd like to be able to group my classes into higher order classes

```
Z = cluster(Y)  # 'LIST_OF_FRUITS','LIST_OF_ANIMALS','LIST_OF_FRUITS'
```

I'm struggling to find something which can do something like this, with or without labeled examples because without defining how large the group I cant see how this could be done.

Also an extension of this which is what I'm actually trying to solve is what if the desired groupings are containing of a few classes of different types not just a concurrent list of "FRUIT" but say a "DINNER" which often will be 0+ "MEATS", 0+ "VEG" etc the ideal solution would be one that knows the atypical dinner and could deduce/correct false negatives and find a dinner grouping from the classified data i.e:

```
Y = ['MEAT','0','0','0','0','MEAT','0','VEG','MEAT'] -> ['DINNER'] (1 instance)
```

Some bag of words encoding of the problem should work but I don't get how to partition the output of classifier 1 such that partitions aren't forced to be a certain size

Is there something that I could use for this?

Comment: your question is not clear. if you already know the labels from a supervised classifier, why you are struggling in grouping the instances? it is straightforward, isn't it? for the second problem, i don't quite understand what is the main issue!!

Comment: The main issue is not knowing how to partition the list of objects, If my higher order classes can contain a non trivial ordering/grouping of subclasses how can I partition? If a "DINNER" can contain '0' or 'FRUIT' or 'MEAT' but with varying frequencys i.e( a dinner would rarely contain '0') how could i partition my output list?

Comment: How would an algorithm know "DINNER"?

Comment: Well, I thought there would be some supervised clustering in which you could provide common examples i.e. "MEAT" "VEG" "0"  | "MEAT" "VEG" "DAIRY" "MEAT" | "MEAT" "VEG" "CARBS". Couldn't find anything however for my purpose I could partition classes by mapping them onto a Y coordinate, then using X as the array position.  For this toy example It's probably not possible because of the features.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you just need to use a classifier with multiple outputs dimensions. This is supported at the low levels, but you won't be able to use a lot of the convenience functions.

For example, I have a model that is a Bag-Of-Words which outputs 4 vectors - classifications - for the Bag-Of-Words vecor list (sentence) at once. They are all linearly independent outputs.

The alternative is to create multiple models for each output dimension.

Comment: The problem with that is not knowing how to partition the output. I'm now thinking the solution could be Agglomerative clustering with a linking constraint such that each cluster only considers neighbors from the original output of classifier, still figuring out how to set number of k clusters however .... http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/cluster/plot_agglomerative_clustering.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-cluster-plot-agglomerative-clustering-py

Answer (score 0):

I don't see clustering here.

If I understand right, you want to partition

```
[Fruit, Meat, Fruit]
```

Into two sets

```
[Fruit, Fruit] and [Meat]
```

At which point you will probably use the cardinality? Then just use a dictionary for counting. I.e. aggregate this into

```
{ Fruit: 2, Meat: 1 }
```

Also, a lot of languages have some syntax to iterate over unique values, and subset operators, so that you can write

```
for x in unique(classification):
  subsets[x] = inputdata[classification == x]
```

Either way, don't look into *clustering* for this. There is no advanced statistical analysis happening here. It's just counting and selecting?

Comment: Thats not quite correct, the idea is to group subclasses into higher order classes, As for not looking into clustering I think your wrong, You gave no solution to how to partition the output list... I mapped features from classifier 1 onto the Y axis and used this to cluster and it works for the intended effect...